# Virtual PC can't be created in Vista Home Premium 

Tags: windows-vista, vmware

According to Microsoft's website, a Virtual PC can't be created in Vista Home Premium. Does anyone know if a VMware VM can be created in Home Premium?

Comment: Consider using VirtualBox: http://virtualbox.org. It's got almost all of the features that VMWare has for a fraction of the cost (free :)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, I do it all the time, e.g. [this tutorial](http://tanguay.info/web2008/tutorial.php?idCode=installUbuntuOnVmware) shows how to install Ubuntu in a VMWare machine, it will work on Vista.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. VMWare's VMs don't use Microsoft's Virtual PC software for virtualization. Two different worlds.

Answer (score 1):

VmWare Server 2.0 is free and web-based. It lets you create vmware virtual machines contrary to vmplayer which is just capable to read an already created virtual machine.

[download it here](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has (arbitrarily) decided that Vista Home Premium users should not be allowed to create VMs using Virtual PC. This is a marketing decision only; there is no limitation in Home Premium per se which prevents third-party software from creating virtual machines.

Comment: I think gus is asking whether you can run Vista Home as the host OS, not the guest OS.

And for what it's worth, Microsoft repealed the ban on running Vista Home as a guest: http://arstechnica.com/old/content/2008/01/microsoft-relents-vista-virtualization-ban-lifted.ars

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the great info. I've created 3 VMs in Vista Home Premium with VMware using Vista as Host.
VM 1 is Windows XP Pro SP 3.
VM 2 is Ubuntu.
VM 3 is Vista Untimate SP 3.
They all seem to be working great.
Thanks for replying.
Gus Herod